# Youtube Embed prevent fullscreen on mobile devices

Tags: video, youtube

I'm building a website which needs to support full and mobile versions, and some pages have youtube iframe:

```
<iframe id="yt-video" width="853" height="480" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?rel=0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Some mobile devices with smaller screens, it looks like it matters, plays video in fullscreen. Is there a way to prevent it and play video normally?

I've tried using `object embed`:

```
<object width="640" height="360">
    <param name="movie" value="https://www.youtube.com/v/M7lc1UVf-VE?version=3"</param>
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"></param>
    <embed src="https://www.youtube.com/v/M7lc1UVf-VE?version=3" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always" width="640" height="360"></embed>
</object>
```

It works as I want to but the problem is that video is not optimized for mobile devices and it lags a lot, at least on my phone, and it's practically impossible to watch.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: ever get a solution to this?

Comment: To be honest I don't remember, it was some time ago :) The final code was using iframe: `<iframe id="yt-video" width="580" height="318" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $video_id; ?>?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Comment: And did it work? Were you able to prevent the fullscreen?

Comment: I do not remember and I can't test it with other devices, at least with my Samsung Note 3 it works fine. There is also possibility that it was left as it is.